# trying to understand how the syntax works in the call back functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I am learning call back functions, but I am confused of the syntax for the below two functions. they are all giving the same result, but written in different syntax, however, why the first one doesn't need to "return result" but the second one does? is that because the "callback(result)" already returned the function and there is no need to return? but for the second merge function, since the callback is on"array1[i], array2[i]", the result need to be returned?

Please correct me if my understanding is not correct. thanks.

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   result[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
  };
callback(result) 
};

var x=merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(merged) {console.log(merged)});
```

---

```
 var merge = function(array1, array2, callback) {
  var result = [];

  for (i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    result[i] = callback(array1[i], array2[i]);   
  }
  return result;
};

var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(a, b){  
  return a + b;
});
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Yeah, those two snippets do two very different things. The first one simply adds the values and passes the final result to the callback. The second one actually calls the callback to get the merged value (i.e. it doesn't have to be addition only) and then directly returns the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will help if you simplify the two pieces of code. Lets consider two different (extremely contrived) ways of "making" and consuming the string "hello".

Your first example is (more or less) equivalent to the following:

```
function makeHello(callback) {
  callback("hello");
}

makeHello(function (str) {
 alert(str) // callback consumes the value produced by the function
});
```

We have a function which produces a value, and makes that value available for consumption by passing it into a callback function. This is primarily used in situations where the value is produced asychronously and cannot be returned from the function.

Your first example, the `merge` function contains the logic for concatenating two arrays ( the `+` operator in this case), and produces the fully merged result itself. It then makes that value available to you via a callback function.

---

Your second example uses a callback for a completely different purpose; its callback is involved in helping to produce the final value:

```
function makeHello(callback) {
  return callback() // callback produces the value we need to return
}

alert(makeHello(function () {
  // callback isn't *consuming* the result, its helping to *produce* the result
  return "hello"
}));
```

Once produced, the function communicates the value by simply returning it. Again, this is only possible because the value is produced in a sychronous manner.

In your second example, the `merge` function doesn't actually know how to merge two arrays. Your callback is responsible for doing this; the `merge` function simply knows how to find the correct pairs and pass them into your callback.

Answer (score 1):

In the second one, you are logging the returned value of the function.

In the first one, you are logging the value of each merge as they happen, but not looking at the returned value. If you had logged the return value, you would see that it is undefined, and also that no values had been actually changed after the merge function had finished execution.

Callback functions do not have to return values. But note that your first version is not returning anything. And that your second version is returning a value. If you were to look only at the returned value then it would show you the difference. The first version would be `undefined`, the second would be `[6,8,10,12]`. The difference is a result of the return. It only looks like the first is returning a value because of the console.log in the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

A callback is just a function that you pass to another function so it can use it to either to return a value back to you (your 1st example) or to be able to customize some part of that receiving function (your 2nd example).

If you were to not use callbacks your code would look like this:

```js
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    result[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
  };
  console.log(result); // this is your callback code
};

merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]);
```

For the 1st example the return is not needed because the **merge** function will give that to the **callback** instead of returning it. So the var x = part is useless, x will be undefined after the call.

Your 2nd example would look like this:

```js
 var merge = function(array1, array2, callback) {
   var result = [];

   for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
     result[i] = a + b; // your callback code gets executed here
   }
   return result;
 };

 var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]);
 console.log(x);
```

For this case the **merge** function actually returns the value but uses the **callback** (this isn't really what you'd call a callback, it's just a function) to customize what action it merges the values in the array by.

Comment: how can i make the second merge function a real callback that doesn't just  customize the array

Comment: you can pass as many functions as you want to the merge function as parameters.